# Is it possible to add apps to the notification bar?

Tags: 12.04, unity, notification-area

How to add apps to the notification bar in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is -- you can't, at least not just any application and not easily. There are specific applications designed to run on the notification bar that are not installed by default, like "indicator-cpufreq"; usually, their name starts with "indicator-something", so you can search for them.